# Show H4 text on the second line inside DIV (if text takes only 1 line)

Tags: css, sass

I have following HTML container with a text inside it:

```
<div class="title"><h4 class=title-text"> Titanic </h4></div>
```

Here is css:

```
.title {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

For the `.title-text`, I added ellipsis, so if the text is longer than 2 lines, It will be cropped:

```
.title-text {
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    text-overflow: -o-ellipsis-lastline;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

This works fine when title text takes 2 lines. I want to achieve following: when the title takes only one line, I need to show this title on the second  line (right now it shows title on the first line) so that it will be closer to the next container below it.

How can I achieve this?

See example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lg21uh8n/2/

In this example, title takes 2 lines. If title is shorter than 1 line, I want to move it on the second line (so the first line is empty and there is empty space above)

Comment: This isn't very clear. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Laif please see this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lg21uh8n/2/ . Updated my question

Comment: Can you just center the title in both scenarios? Why is the header container a fixed height?

Comment: @Laif no, I can't. The requirement is to show 2-lines title as it is in the fiddle example right now, and start showing the title on the second line, if the title is short enough to fit one line. Header container has a fixed width, because parent of it's parent has a fixed width. For the simplicity, I added the width to it here (so I don't need to post entire HTML block)

Comment: You can't do that with CSS.

Comment: what happens about Opera and IE browsers which do not support `webkit-` prefixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think you can achieve this using flexbox:

https://jsfiddle.net/tedw/musy3pfc/

```css
.title-text {
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    text-overflow: -o-ellipsis-lastline;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1em;
    top: 0;
    margin:0;
    left: 0;
}

.title {
    align-items: flex-end;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 83px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="title"><h4 class="title-text"> Titanic titanic titanic</h4></div>
  
  <div class="title"><h4 class="title-text"> titanic titanic titanic titanic Titanic titanic titanic Titanic titanic titanic Titanic </h4></div>

</div>
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, will learn how to use flex properties

Comment: Great, glad that worked! FWIW, my favorite flexbox reference is https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/. I refer to it often since the flexbox syntax isn’t very intuitive IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the material, very useful. While the approach with flex box you suggested works perfectly for most of the cases, I wonder if it possible to do following in css: in SOME cases, my title text span has one more span before it( called "title-prefix-text"): see this: https://jsfiddle.net/vb47nkpm/ .

 In such cases, using "display:fllex" for 2 lines long titles that also have a prefix, displays title and title prefix incorrectly (see fiddle for example). I cannot merge together title and title prefix in one span, as I need to apply different font styles for the title prefix span.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the prefix text from wrapping? If so, you could try adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the prefix `<span>` or adding `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the `.title` wrapper.

Comment: The first approach didn't work. With `flex-wrap: wrap` I got almost what I need, but still the prefix showed not on the same line as a title text. Is it possible to make both title and title prefix inline in this case? https://jsfiddle.net/tr6p3jcv/ (see the 4th block)

Comment: I think you may need an additional wrapper element. Is this what you’re after? https://jsfiddle.net/tedw/yL07rn8z/6/

Comment: Almost. I need to have both Title Prefix and Title strings to start on the same line (this works with a wrapper in your approach). However, I also need to remove the gap on the second line: so the title string continues below the Title Prefix. (I'm referring to the div #4, where there is both Title Prefix and Long title)

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now. I refactored the demo a bit https://jsfiddle.net/tedw/yL07rn8z/24/ Note that this won’t work in IE11 or below. If you need deep browser support, I would suggest using https://dollarshaveclub.github.io/shave/